# what's an elegant way to implement a js getter in this scenario?

Tags: javascript

I have the following globals js module:

```
var globals = (function (){
   var selectedReportPeriodId = 2;
   return{
      SelectedReportPeriodId : selectedReportPeriodId 
   };
})();
```

My code sets SelectedReportPeriodId based on the report period option that the user selects. I want to add a js getter to this module which would functionally work like this:

```
function IsCurrentReportPeriod()
{
   return selectedReportPeriodId === 1
}
```

I'd like downstream code to call the getter like this:

```
if(globals.IsCurrentReportPeriod)
{
   //do this
}
```

What would be an elegant way to implement this as a getter in the js module above?

***UPDATE #1***

I tried to implement like this:

```
var globals = (function (){

   var selectedReportPeriodId;

   return{
      SelectedReportPeriodId : selectedReportPeriodId,
      get IsCurrentReportPeriod() {
         return selectedReportPeriodId == 1;
      }
   };
})();
```

I'm setting globals.SelectedReportPeriodId = 1 in previous code. I also set a breakpoint in a method and set a watch of globals.SelectedReportPeriodId which returns 1. However, globals.IsCurrentReportPeriod returns false in the line below this code so my getter as defined does not seem to be working as expected.  Any suggestions?

***UPDATE #2***

selectedReportPeriodId is initialized with a value of 2.  I'm guessing that this may be a reason why the getter sees selectedReportPeriodId = 2 instead of 1 even after the updated value is set.  What is a good solution for this? Should I make a getter for selectedReportPeriodId as well which does some conditional logic as opposed to initializing with a hard-coded value?

Answer (score 0):

```
return{
      SelectedReportPeriodId : selectedReportPeriodId,
      IsCurrentReportPeriod : function () {
          return selectedReportPeriodId === 1
      }
};
```

But your call will have to look like this:

```
if (globals.IsCurrentReportPeriod()) {
}
```

Comment: thanks steve but i would prefer to use a property in this scenario

Comment: "property" and "getter" are mutually exclusive.  A getter, by definition is a function.   If you have to use a property, we'd need more info for an example.  You will need to set a new propery based on your condition during the events that trigger a change in "SelectedReportPeriodId" property.  Set both properties (which is also not elegant and is excessive coupling) - otherwise use a function as in my example, which is elegant and a getter (which is what I think you asked for), and is really in line with how JS is engineered.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward and simple solution would be to let your code set the `globals.IsCurrentReportPeriod` property instead of the `selectedReportPeriodId` variable. But if you absolutely have to use a getter, you can do so:

```
var globals = (function (){
    var selectedReportPeriodId;
    return {
        get IsCurrentReportPeriod() {
            return selectedReportPeriodId === 1;
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way of created module :

```js
var Globals = Globals || {};

(function(exports) {
   var selectedReportPeriodId = 1,
       otherPrivateVariable = 'private !';
   
   exports.getIsCurrentReportPeriod = function() {
     return (selectedReportPeriodId === 1);
   };

   function thisIsAPrivateMethod() {
   }

})(Globals);

alert(Globals.getIsCurrentReportPeriod())
```